# Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait on jmeter with groovy

Tags: java, selenium, groovy, jmeter

I am currently writing a script on jmeter with the selenium library with groovy on jmeter, but I encounter a problem. I did several tests before in java directly but never got it. I think groovy does not understand a selenium library which is WebDriverWait, all the others work and pass all the tests but this one does not work, if you have more info I'm interested.

Here is the code and the error :

**Code**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setAcceptInsecureCerts(true).addArguments("--marionette-port").addArguments("-private");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
    
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String baseUrl = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com";
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get(baseUrl);

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
```

**Error**

```
022-08-23 11:48:22,603 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.J.JSR223 Sampler: Uncaught error: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait(org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver, java.time.Duration)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1845)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1615)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.MetaClassConstructorSite.callConstructor(MetaClassConstructorSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:286)
    at Script69.run(Script69.groovy:32)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:155)
    at java.scripting/javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:231)
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:219)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Thank you for reading and for your time, hoping you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest [WebDriver Sampler plugin version 3.3](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/kg.apc/jmeter-plugins-webdriver/3.3) comes with [selenium-support 3.141.59](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/3.141.59) and looking into the [JavaDoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support/3.141.59/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) there is no such a constructor which accepts [Duration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) as a parameter so you need to either provide the timeout in seconds like:

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 10L);
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this exact error came to be as a result of upgrading JMeter to the latest version (5.5) and having in my Selenium script

`def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)`

and I had to replace it with:

`def wait = new WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, Duration.ofSeconds(5))`

I also had to `import java.time.Duration`